# PHP: authenticate for a REST request?

Tags: rest-api, authentication

I did create some custom endpoints for a plugin i'm working on, with the REST api.
It works quite well, but now I would like to secure those requests : I don't want external users (**EDIT:** I mean remote requests) to be able to do query them.

But I only find documentation about javascript authentification ([REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/)).
How should I achieve authentification with PHP (WP 5.1.1 here) ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by "external users"? 
If you only want Users, that are logged into your website, to use the API Endpoint, you can filter the "rest_authentication_errors" like described [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#require-authentication-for-all-requests)

Add this to your plugin:

```
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
    if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
        return $result;
    }
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rest_not_logged_in', 'You are not currently logged in.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    }
    return $result;
});
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Yes, almost - and what if I would like to give some external users access to it ? With a client ID + secret or something ? Thanks.

Comment: Then you don't use this code but instead one of the many Authentification Methods like oAuth, Application Passwords or Basic Authentification (more here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins) and use checks for your REST-API-Endpoint with current_user_can ^^